# AR_mailer throwing exception. Mail still sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ar-mailer

I'm setting up AR_mailer to send mail. All works from a sending point of view, but when the mail is actually created I receive this error:

```
A LoadError occurred in users#create:

 Expected /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/adzap-ar_mailer-2.1.5/lib/action_mailer/ar_mailer.rb to define ActionMailer::ARMailer
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:261:in `load_missing_constant'
```

The mail is still added to the queue though.

I'm using ad_zap's AR_mailer fork (http://github.com/adzap/ar_mailer/tree/master) version 2.1.5, with Rails 2.1.0

Thanks
Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was caused by my upgrading from an older version of ARMailer.

I needed to change my mailers to inherit from ActionMailer::Base, and not ActionMailer::ARMailer as with the previous version.